amCharts5 error creating a new root element
i generated a new compoent, imported the scripts to html file via CDN, and imported all core of am5 charts, xycharts & stock. now as soon as i try to create the root element and refresh the page, i get below error

error: [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /main.server.mjs:
|- ReferenceError: requestAnimationFrame is not defined

code to create root element:
let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
[error image](https://i.sstatic.net/XzOgP.png)
[basic code start](https://i.sstatic.net/RcuN8.png)

i was trying to create the root element where i can lager add the chart.

have you defined a dom element with the same chart id ("chartdiv" in your case)
